# Spring XD - Mail as Sink or Source

Tags: spring, email, sink

I have been trying to ingest data from **Mail** to **File** using Spring XD. Although the creation of the stream comes out to be successful, no output file is created in the process.

**The command I used is as follows:**

```
xd:>stream create mailtest --definition "mail --username=myemail%40gmail.com --password=mypassword --host=imap.gmail.com --delete=false --port=993 --outputType=text/plain | file" --deploy
```

What can I do to fix this?

Moreover, the same problem is occurring when I use **Mail** as **Sink**. In the example I did, I  used **HTTP** as my **Source**.

**The commands I used are as follows:**

```
xd:>stream create toMail --definition "HTTP | mail --host=imap.gmail.com --to='\"some.email.com@gmail.com\"' --username=myemail%40gmail.com --subject='testing mail' --password=mypassword --port=993 --contentType=text/plain" --deploy

xd:> http post --target http://localhost:9000 --data "hello world!"
```

Your feedback is much appreciated!